# WPF Screen should show hotkeys alltime without pressing Alt key

Tags: wpf-controls

I want to show the hotkeys for label, button on screen without pressing Alt Key. For example
Alt + N opens new dialog where N is hot key so I want underline always appears below N.

I am not sure how we can achieve this without Pressing alt key. After pressing Alt Key hot key is shown but we want to show the corresponding hot key all the time till the screen is open.

Answer (score 1):

I answered in [this nearly identical question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1021227/is-there-a-way-to-press-or-fireup-the-keys-in-key-board-using-c-code/1021598#1021598) that

> If you have any control over the operating system on which the program is being deployed, apparently you can force the underlined shortcut letter to always be displayed by going to Control Panel -> Display -> Appearance -> Effects -> Hide underlined letters for keyboard navigation.

If you can't do that, some of the other answers mentioned using a [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.aspx) class.